# Web socket & Flash socket clients connect to one Node.js

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, websocket, flashsocket, engine.io

I've got problem connecting Flash client to Node.js server.

**Short story**:

For a first time I'm building a Node.js server that should be used by both web client (WebSocket) as well as a Flash client (Socket). The web client, of course, works like a charm, but I can't get over the Flash one. I get SECURITY_ERROR. After a day of research I think it's because of the policy file not being loaded. Ideas (primus on top of engine.io) ?

**Long story**:

I'm using [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) as I thought I'll need it because I have both web sockets and flash sockets to handle. Not sure if this is accurate? :)

I'm using [Engine.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io) as a 'transformer/transporter' - the main framework that the layer uses. I won't discuss the standard web client (using Chrome and primus-client), as it's easy to setup.

I'm using simple and standard Sockets in AS3:

```
_socket = new Socket();
_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onSocketConnect);
//...
_socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
_socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);

_socket.connect('localhost', '1337);
```

When building it within Flash IDE, it goes to the `onSocketConnect` function, but if I try to write anything to the socked - I get disconnected. If I run this from the web browser, I get into the `onSecurityError` method.

I must say that I don't get any traces in the node console!

```
primus.on('connection', function connection(spark) {
  console.log('new connection'); // never gets logged!
```

As I know, security error is thrown when there is error with the policy file, so I started searching for a solution for that.

I've read a lot of things online, and most common solution was simple usage of `socket.io` and so called [`FlashSocket.IO`](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO). I tried implementing it, but it's so old, that some of the code is a kind of missing and I finally got some errors from the `hurlant` library - I couldn't get it working.

I also saw some node package called `policy`, which runs separate server to server the policy file.

I tried adding a `transport` array with `flashsocket` in it - no change. I also can't understand why all of the samples are using `transports` - I've searched and both `index.js` and `primus.js` are using `transport` (why there are two separate files, Jesus?!)

I could try using only `engine.io` without `primus`, but I don't know if this would be of any help. All the posts and samples I've found are pretty old - please help me with any up to date solution or at least some explanation what needs to be done - seems like a whole new universe to me :)

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:*
Thanks to the The_asMan, I figured out it has something to do with the handshake. I've tried [this](http://walnutfish.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/flash-sockets-with-node-js/) simple example (despite the fact it's so old) - it worked perfectly **for the Flash client**! Of course I cannot connect web sockets to it, as the handshake is not proper - it has some kind of protocol for it.

So I guess I just have to understand how to get the `<policy-file-request/>` in node - I'll be able to return the policy file. But I don't know how to get it - I don't receive any kind of `data` nor `connect` handler...

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - Flash/AIR Socket Communication writeUTFBytes only works once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978480/as3-flash-air-socket-communication-writeutfbytes-only-works-once)

Answer (score 0):

You have a cross domain policy issue.

I answered it all here.

[AS3 - Flash/AIR Socket Communication writeUTFBytes only works once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978480/as3-flash-air-socket-communication-writeutfbytes-only-works-once/5982293#5982293)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said - I understand that there is policy issue, I just can't figure out how to fix it :) As I'm using `engine.io`, there is no `connected` event fired there, so I cannot even send the policy file back. Maybe there is something in the handshake that I'm missing..

Comment: @AndreyPopov A policy file request is a request like any other - you should just be able to add a handler for the url, and serve up the policy file, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said, the server doesn't even get a `connect` handler, so it cannot send any response. I think it's because of all those frameworks and wrappers, because the most basic implementations work. But I don't need only Flash socket server, I would like to use it along with Web Sockets..

Answer (score 0):

just an idea: 
On some operating systems, flush() is called automatically between execution frames, but on other operating systems, such as Windows, the data is never sent unless you call flush() explicitly. To ensure your application behaves reliably across all operating systems, it is a good practice to call the flush() method after writing each message (or related group of data) to the socket.